# how to add more than one service to ingress with url maps?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backend, url-mapping, kubernetes-ingress

Hi I have four microservices running and i want to use one ingress lb for all of those.
Problem here is my ingress is working for only one microservice. but my application has some url like index.html. which means I have to access http:///**index.html**
If I access  http:/// (**it shows white label page error**)
when I am using url-maps with path as path1 and I am trying to access http:///path1 (it shows white label page error). which means backend are working.But when I am try to access http:///path1/index.html it shows backend not found.

I need to know how to use url-maps in this case. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example extracted from the Kubernetes documentation [1] that creates 1 ingress load balancer that points to diferent backend services:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: s2
          servicePort: 80
```

You can add as many back end services as you need.

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, Here My problem is little different. I am able to use more than one backend but It is showing whitelabel page error. If i give /index.html it will work but that is not the path for the lb

Comment: What output does give you http:///path1/ ? Also what do you mean by "It is showing whitelabel page error." 404 error?